# windows 10 file explorer causes wi-fi hang

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-explorer

I faced such problem on my HP (desktop PC): starting file explorer or opening file selection dialog causes network hang. Network hangs for 5-10 seconds. It is stably reproduced. All drivers updated.

Without interaction with the explorer, wi-fi works stably.

```
Windows 10 build 18363
Wi-Fi adapter Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter
```

Router ping output

```
...
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=5.25 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=11.1 ms
---> here wentwork hangs
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=4.51 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=3.45 ms
...
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is there any solution?

Comment: Are there any items in QuickAccess which point to files elsewhere on your LAN, or any mapped network drives?

Comment: Nothing, no any cloud and network drives.

Comment: No any explorer plugins, I removed all printers, stopped all third party services, disabled autostart programs, checked for viruses, recovered system files, but nothing helped